# Get maximum greater key values with object of array

Tags: javascript, function, es6-promise

I want the maximum key of an object into an array in Javascript, the following is the example of an array of JSON. I tried with reduce() ES6 function, but it will return only on record, So please help me to get maximum no. of key array, i provide also output what i want, It will be great if the solution in high order functions(ES6)

```
let arr = [{
                key : 1,
                name : 'testaa',
                dept : 'ggg'
            }, {
                key : 1,
                name : 'testaa',
                dept : 'ggg'
            }, {
                key : 2,
                name : 'testaa',
                dept : 'ggg'
            }, {
                key : 2,
                name : 'testaa',
                dept : 'ggg'
            }, {
                key : 2,
                name : 'testaa',
                dept : 'ggg'
            }, {
                key : 3,
                name : 'testaa',
                dept : 'ggg'
            }, {
                key : 3,
                name : 'testaa',
                dept : 'ggg'
            }]

 output i want maximum key of array:


    arr = [{
                key : 3,
                name : 'testaa',
                dept : 'ggg'
            }, {
                key : 3,
                name : 'testaa',
                dept : 'ggg'
            }]
```

I tried with reduce function but getting only one records

```
let data = myArray.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.key > curr.key ? prev : curr;
});
```

Comment: `{
                key = 1,
                name = 'testaa',
                dept = 'ggg'
            }` is not valid syntax `=` should be `:`

Comment: reduce is only going to return one value.....and you do not set the reducer up with a default value to start....

Comment: You say you want the maximum key. Your reduce call returns the maximum key. So what else do you want (when you say "only one")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were only returning the last higher key. You have to build an array containing all the elements that have the higher key.

In my algorithm, I store the highest key in an array, when I encounter an element with an higher key than the elements that I stored, I whipe the array and recreate one.

```js
const arr = [{
  key: 1,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}, {
  key: 1,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}, {
  key: 2,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}, {
  key: 2,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}, {
  key: 2,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}, {
  key: 3,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}, {
  key: 3,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}];

const higherKey = arr.reduce((tmp, x) => {
  if (!tmp.length || tmp[0].key < x.key) {
    return [x];
  }

  if (tmp[0].key === x.key) {
    tmp.push(x);
  }

  return tmp;
}, []);

console.log(higherKey);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in two steps:

1. Find the highest value using [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)
2. Filter your array with this value using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let arr = [{
  key: 1,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}, {
  key: 1,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}, {
  key: 2,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}, {
  key: 2,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}, {
  key: 2,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}, {
  key: 3,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}, {
  key: 3,
  name: 'testaa',
  dept: 'ggg'
}];

let max = Math.max(...arr.map(item => item.key));

console.log(arr.filter(item => item.key === max));
```

Comment: Serge K thanks for the solution, I agree with your solution but, you are iterating two times one for map() and another for filter(), We can do this in reduce() function only one iteration.

Comment: @sarveshkumar See [Gregory NEUT answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55165701/3054411)

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [{
    key : 1,
    name : 'testaa',
    dept : 'ggg'
}, {
    key : 1,
    name : 'testaa',
    dept : 'ggg'
}, {
    key : 3,
    name : 'testaa',
    dept : 'ggg'
}, {
    key : 2,
    name : 'testaa',
    dept : 'ggg'
}, {
    key : 2,
    name : 'testaa',
    dept : 'ggg'
}, {
    key : 8,
    name : 'testaa',
    dept : 'ggg'
}, {
    key : 3,
    name : 'testaa',
    dept : 'ggg'
}]
let max = arr[0];
let data = arr.forEach(function(curr,index) {
if(max.key < curr.key) {
max = curr;
}
});
result = arr.map((item) => {
return item.key === map.key;
});
console.log(result)
```

I would suggest to use two loops one for finding out the max key and then filter those keys, complexity would be o(n)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `reduce`, in a single iteration, you can use it like that (it's really verbose, you can simplify if you want):

```
let data = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    // If there is not data on the accumulator, add the first element
    if (acc.length === 0) {
        acc.push(curr);
        return acc;
    }
    // if current key is smaller than the stored one, clear and start a new accumulator
    if (acc[0].key < curr.key) {
        acc = [];
        acc.push(curr);
    }
    // If key is the same than the stored one, add it to the accumulator
    else if(acc[0].key === curr.key) {
        acc.push(curr);
    }

    // Return the accumulator
    return acc;
}, []);
```